# Charge congjuation and Transition form factors

Tags: symmetry, protons, charge-conjugation, hadron-dynamics

Let us consider the transition form factor of proton to Delta (see reference of https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.100.034001):

$\gamma^{\ast}p \to \Delta$.

Then we should also have the timelike transtion form factor of antiproton and  Delta:

$\gamma^{\ast} \to \bar{p} \Delta$,

however,the Charge congjuation of the photon is -, and $ \bar{p} \Delta$ system does not have Charge congjuation, so how can we understand the Charge congjuation in $\gamma^{\ast} \to \bar{p} \Delta$?